# Java byte[] to string conversion outputting byte

Tags: java, string, arrays

In my code, I am sending a txt file encoded into a byte array over the internet, and then converting the message back on the other side and displaying it. The problem is that when I try displaying it, it always comes out as "[B@1ef9f1d" or "[B@1764be1" etc.

This is what recieves the data

```
private void parsePacket(byte[] data, InetAddress address, int port) {
    String datasent[] = (new String(data).trim()).split(",");
    String type = datasent[0];
    String message = datasent[1];
    switch(type){//Data we are receiving from client, type is 5 char
    default:
        System.out.println(type);
        System.out.println(message);
    case "invalid":
        println("Invalid packet", new Color(255, 155, 155));
        break;
    case "login":
        addConnection(message, address, port);
        break;
    case "SendLog":
        printLog(message);
        break;
    }
}
private void printLog(String message) {
    int charperline = 10;
    String line ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length() / charperline; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < charperline; j++){
        line += message.charAt(i + j);
        }
        println("LOG: " + line);
        line = "";
    }

}
```

And this is what sends it:

```
public void sendLog(){
    System.out.println("sendlog()");
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/LOG.txt");
    try
    {
        byte[] text = new byte[10000];
        is.read(text);
            sendData(("SendLog," + text).getBytes());
        //is.close();
        new File("/LOG.txt").delete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
public void sendData(byte[] data){
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, 1332);
    try {
        socket.send(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing

```
[B@1ef9f1d
```

is the result of the method `toString()` that all classes inherit from the `Object` class, since all classes in Java extend `Object`. This is implemented as

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

In this case, `getClass().getName()` would return `[B` because it is an array of Bytes.

This is because array objects in Java do not have a custom `toString()` method, they inherit `Object`'s.

If you want to print the contents of an array, try

```
Arrays.toString(yourByteArray);
```

For custom classes, you should always implement (override) your own custom `toString()` method. It is useful for logging. Note that String concatenation when used with reference types uses the `toString()` method implicitly to convert your object into a String representation.

Comment: +1 for Array.toString, actually had no idea it existed. And custom toString = good

Comment: Thank you! But now, it's displayed as an array of ints? [32, 56, ...]

Comment: @Kyranstar You're welcome. A `byte` is represented as an integer from `-128` to `127`. Did you want a binary representation? As in `00010101`? You'll have to do the formatting yourself, but methods exist in the JDK to do that.